# animation not very smooth

Tags: jquery

I have created a small slide show. However, it doesn't really look very smooth. How can I make the transitions look smoother?

Here's the relevant code. wod is a variable in this case 350px . tranSpeed is 1000 and is time for the animation to occur. I have tried setting this to different values, and still get the same jagged appearence.

```
$('#slideShowInner').stop(true,true).animate({'left':'-=' + wod}, tranSpeed, function (){ autoSlide = setTimeout(fred, slidetime) });
```

You can see what I mean at http://www.en2krew.com/clothing.html

Thanks

Here is the html code that is used:

```
<div id="slideShowWindow">
<div id="slideShowInner">    
<img src="images/clothingphotos/sonnytshirt.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
<img src="images/clothingphotos/bethtshirt.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
<img src="images/clothingphotos/mayaelliejesstshirt.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
<img src="images/clothingphotos/alfiemilessebtshirt.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
<img src="images/clothingphotos/geehat.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
<img src="images/clothingphotos/aaronhat.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="350" />
</div>
<div id="buttons">
<img id="clickPrev" src="images/prevButton.jpg" height="17" width="15" />  
<img id="clickNext" src="images/nextButton.jpg" height="17" width="15" />
<div id="pauseHolder">
<img class="clickMe" id="clickPause" src="images/pauseButton.jpg" height="17" width="15" />
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<!-- buttons--></div>
<!-- slideShowWindow --></div>
```

Comment: It looks perfectly smooth to me. Using IE9. (Meaning this is probably a browser issue)

Comment: Looks good in Chrome as well.

Comment: Same in safari. If you're using an older ie js can be a dog.

Comment: Fine in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome Dev.

Comment: many thanks for your comments! Its IE8 that's jagged = does that count as old???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't the p tags issue although I took note of that for later jQuery thingies. There where no p tags in this project.

I figured it might be margins/padding - but still doing it when I took them off.

In the end I sort of "Gave up" with this. Its fine in everything - even IE9. In IE8 it cxould be taht I am looking on a laptop (albeit a good one, and FF, Saf etc are good...)

I decided to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer overhaul]

I researched with me friend googles.

Turns out it **could** be IE, jQuery and `<p>` tags.

Change the `<p>`'s to something else.

Comment: thanks - as I see the images move the edges of them appear jagged. I have noticed that it looks jagged in IE8. But better in saf, FF and opera.

Comment: Will try a easing solution as well

Comment: tried an easing solution - didn't make a lot of difference (if any). But thanks for the tip

Comment: Thanks Neurofluxation - was interested in what you said about <p> - i have posted the html up above - there are no <p> or am I missing something?

Comment: Afraid I'm out of ideas then Maxelcat, try using it on a different computer?

Comment: Well, thanks again. You last comment has got me thinking - I suspect its a margin/padding thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the left position to an absolute value instead of iterating in smaller increments:

```
$('#slideShowInner').stop(true,true).animate({
    'left':'=' + wodFinal //set final value and loop fewer times
}, tranSpeed, 'easingName', function (){ 
    autoSlide = setTimeout(fred, slidetime) 
})
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but I think it is an absolute value - there is no loop

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I found this [tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/animation-jump-quick-tip/comment-page-2/#comment-1169) very helpfull. Basically has to do with margins & padding